# Ionic 2 - Using JSON array in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic2

I have an array of JSON objects named 'books', however I can't seem to extract any of the information for use in the HTML.

The array is in the form :

[image: Console log of array form]

Each object is in the form:

[image: Form of JSON object]

I am trying to access fields such as isbn13 from the HTML file. As follows:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let book of books">
    {{book.data.isbn13}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

This code throws no error but displays no text. If I reduce it to {{book.data}} it prints [object Object] for each entry in the array.

How can I access isbn13?

Comment: i think theres a typo. In your `*ngFor` you are trying to display `isb13` and not `isbn13`.

Comment: Adding to @AakashThakur comment, the path seems to be `book.data[0].isbn13`.

Comment: Thank you everybody! Indeed data[0] was the problem!

Comment: @AakashThakur What is the recommended method to use for deleting a specific object from the array>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a mistake. Data is and array, not an object. So you need to access the first element of array.

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let book of books">
     {{book.data[0].isbn13}}
   </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how that mistake arrived, it must have been while copying in to the question. {{book.data.isbn13}} still gives no output.

Comment: Nice edit dude. Read the above comments in time. haha.

Comment: Perfect! It is working now, I will accept the answer ad soon as the time limit allows me to. Thanks!